# Group by error caused by min fuction in case statement in select statement

Tags: sql

I have been adding a min function in a case statement and getting an error.  Is this not allowed or am I just doing something wrong?

Previously I built a virtual table with this min date and linked to it, but this feels rather inefficient.  Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
SELECT 
UNIQUE_ID, 
sum(CASE 
WHEN TRAN_TYPE NOT IN('D') THEN 0 
WHEN TRANSACTION > 0 THEN TRAN_AMNT 
WHEN (TRAN_DATE > (min(CASE WHEN TRAN_TYPE = 'N' THEN TRAN_DATE ELSE null END) + 30)) THEN 0 
ELSE TRAN_AMNT END) as GROSS_LOSS
FROM 
TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
TRAN_DATE between '01-jan-2003' and '28-feb-2018' AND 
TRAN_TYPE NOT IN('X') AND 
GROUP BY 
UNIQUE_ID, 
HAVING 
sum(TRAN_AMNT) >= 5000000
```

Comment: Please apply proper formatting to your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query as you have written it.  I have highlighted the obvious syntax errors

```
SELECT UNIQUE_ID,
       sum(CASE WHEN TRAN_TYPE NOT IN ('D') THEN 0
                WHEN TRANSACTION > 0 THEN TRAN_AMNT
                WHEN (TRAN_DATE > (min(CASE WHEN TRAN_TYPE = 'N' THEN TRAN_DATE ELSE null END) + 30))
-----------------------------------^ aggregation function within an aggregation function
                THEN 0
                ELSE TRAN_AMNT
            END) as GROSS_LOSS
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2003-01-01' AND '2018-02-28' AND  -- fixed the date formats
      TRAN_TYPE NOT IN ('X') AND
-----------------------------^ And what?
GROUP BY UNIQUE_ID,
------------------^ extra comma
HAVING sum(TRAN_AMNT) >= 5000000;
```

The answer to your question is that you cannot nest aggregation functions like that.  You need to fix the other errors as well.

It is a bit hard to suggest what to fix, because you don't describe the logic that you really want.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. 

A little bit more about this database table and that I am trying to divine out of it.  The table is made up of transactions.  There are different types of transactions (let’s call them N-O-P), some are used for financial reporting and some are used for risk management, etc.  Related transactions can be grouped together under UNIQUE_ID (I should have picked a better name).

Comment: What I am hoping to accomplish is to get the sum of all “N” type transactions under the same UNIQUE_ID that are either:

(a)    Occurring within the first 30 days of the earliest transaction

(b)   Or positive outside of the 30 day window

Comment: @Greg . . . Ask another question.  Describe the data that you have.  Describe the result that you want and the transformations.  You can also include SQL to show your attempt at solving the problem.  This appears to answer this specific question, which is about a syntax error.